# bash with regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file with GC content like `Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0017830 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002897 seconds` and many more similar lines. For troubleshooting purpose I need to extract the lines where `stopped:` will more than `1.x` sec.

I did tried with `grep 'stopped[: 1-9]*'` but I am not much expert with regex usage. Could you please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it not be easier to simply **exclude** those where the time was low?

```
grep 'stopped: ' | grep -v 'stopped: 0'
```

Comment: aah! How I missed -v option.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 grep -E 'stopped: ([1-9]\.|[0-9]{2}\.)' file
```

to capture 10. as well.

or, better to factor out the common element and allow more digits than 2.

```
 grep -E 'stopped: ([1-9]|[0-9]{2,})\.' file
```

Comment: You just changed the way I should think to make this as perfect solution, :)

Comment: [1-9]\.|[0-9]{2}\.) , Here [1-9] is for first match and for decimal you have added dot(.) and escaped it with backslash(\) so it should consider as normal character and {2} for next two decimals . so 00 to 99. but why that last dot(.) and why you have escaped it ? I just cant link only this part to my question. Could you please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it will match `00.` as but I didn't think it's a valid format to consider (unnecessary leading zeros).  This simply says either its 1-9 before the decimal point or a two digit number before the decimal point.  Assumes leading digit is a significant number without leading zeros.  Note this won't capture 3 or more digits as well.  I edited to include them.

Comment: @ccf I understand that , I am just trying to interpret the regex

Comment: The check is regex equivalent of greater than 1.  Translation is: if it's a single digit it should be 1 or more; or, at least two digits before the decimal point.

Comment: @karakfa , you did grouping here [1-9]|[0-9]{2,})\. , so it seems it can deal more better.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [`egrep`](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~tal/3261/fall07/handout/egrep_mini-tutorial.htm) for this job which gives you more regex options.

Here's a starting point for a regex that may fit your use-case:

```
egrep "stopped: [0-9]+" data.txt
```

This will return any line that has `stopped:` in it followed by at least one number.

Comment: @Raja: But how it will filter results for values greater than `1.x sec`

Comment: @anubhava I modified it as per my needs , `echo " application threads were stopped: 7.0011040 seconds" | egrep "stopped: [1-9]+"` and output 
 `application threads were stopped: 7.0011040 seconds`

Answer (score 1):

You can use gnu-awk using `FPAT` variable:

```
awk -v FPAT="stopped: *[0-9.]+" '{val=$1; sub(/.*: */, "", val)} val > 1' file
```

Using `FPAT` we're matching only `stopped: *[0-9.]+` regex as a field. That gives us something like `stopped: 1.1017830` in `$1`. Using `sub` function we remove everything before `:` and following space thus leaving only the number i.e. `1.1017830` in variable `val`.

Finally `val > 1` will print rows where this number `val` is greater than `1`.

Comment: Can you explain , its a bit hard to understand.

Comment: I've added some explanation in my answer.

Comment: Excellent Anubhava :)

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E 'Stopping.*[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+' file
```

`[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+` is to make sure "more than 1.x sec"